# Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart - add_series(): name-property-question

Tags: perl, excel, charts, spreadsheet

When I use a formula to ad the name it works (first series: `Max.`), but when I write the name directly, I get the default name (second series: `Column B` instead of `Min.`).
Why does the second method not work here?
In [Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart#CHART_METHODS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX%3a%3aChart#CHART_METHODS) is an example which does pass the name-attribute directly.
I'm opening the file with LibreOffice.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'spreadsheet.xlsx' ) or die $!;
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet( 'One' );
my $ref = [
[ 'Max.', 'Min.' ],
[ 7, 5 ],
[ 11, 5 ],
[ 9, 2 ],
[ 8, 5 ], ];
$worksheet->write_col( 0, 0, $ref );

my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'line' );

$chart->add_series(
    values => [ 'One', 1, $#$ref, 0, 0 ],
    name => '=One!$A$1',
);

$chart->add_series(
    values => [ 'One', 1, $#$ref, 1, 1 ],
    name => 'Min.',
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with LibreOffice. The chart legend displays as expected in Excel 2007 (see below).

However, I see the same behaviour as you described in LibreOffice 3.3.3 even with files produced by Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works with LibreOffice 3.4.0.